# In Gnome3, how do I create a keyboard shortcut for opening a file with a variable in the file name?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gnome, gvim, gnome3

Typing `gvim note_$(date +%F).md` in terminal, opens a file in `gvim` that has today's date in the title. When I try to bind a keyboard shortcut to the same command, `gvim` throws an error message:

```
"note_$(date" [New File]
Error detected while processing command line:
E492: Not an editor command: ).md
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

The file title reads `note_$(date (~)`. I have tried with backticks and `expr`, but I receive the same error. I am on Gnome3 and trying to create the shortcut via `Keyboard >> Shortcuts >> Custom Shortcuts`.

How should I go about getting the keyboard shortcut command to work the same way as when typed directly in the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out that the command runs fine if I put it in a script and then just assign a keyboard shortcut to the script. So in `/path/to/file`:

```
#!/bin/bash
gvim note_$(date +%F).md
```

Make the script executable (`chmod +x /path/to/file`), and in the 'command'-field for the shortcut, just put `path/to/file`.